# Incorrect slicing behavior for Pandas DataFrame loc index

Tags: python, pandas

I think the loc slicing for [0:0] should produce empty output. Is it a bug?

```
>>> df
   0   1   2   3
0  1  21  51  61
1  2  22  52  62
2  3  23  53  63
>>> df.loc[0:0]
   0   1   2   3
0  1  21  51  61
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, location-based indexing has *inclusive* endpoints for `pandas` data-structures. See [Miscellaneous indexing FAQ](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-endpoints-are-inclusive).

> Compared with standard Python sequence slicing in which the slice
> endpoint is not inclusive, label-based slicing in pandas is inclusive.
> The primary reason for this is that it is often not possible to easily
> determine the “successor” or next element after a particular label in
> an index.

If you used integer position based indexing, like `iloc`, this will behave like vanilla `python` data structures:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   0   1   2   3
0  1  21  51  61
1  2  22  52  62
2  3  23  53  63

In [6]: df.iloc[0:0]
Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Index: []

In [7]: df.loc[0:0]
Out[7]:
   0   1   2   3
0  1  21  51  61

In [8]:
```

Comment: Very nice answer. However, this behavior is frustrating and unintuitive

Comment: Not the right forum to ask this question. But an average developer would have been happier if slicing was disabled/raised-error  than  give a slightly different behavior!!

Comment: @Ajeet no, location-based slicing is amazing and would make any developer happier. The average developer would be happier if they read the documentation.

Comment: I love python because I don't have to read documentation for expected behavior. 
Personally, I don't like inconsistent slicing, and I am sure there are yet unknown bugs due to this.

Comment: Just found out this was causing a bug in my program! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Slicing is typically inclusive on the first index and exclusive on the second. For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
print x[0:0]
# prints [], the empty list.
```

However, says plain as day in the docs that both start and end index are inclusive for the `loc` function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

> A slice object with labels, e.g. 'a':'f' (note that contrary to usual
>   python slices, both the start and the stop are included!).

Why Pandas wanted to troll you like this? Only God knows.

Comment: Why on earth they would introduce a behavior inconsistent with the language semantics ???

Comment: I am not sure, I'm sort of grumpy now too. I actually didn't know this until you posted it (I don't use Panda's often, just pure numpy typically does the trick for me)